# Change content according to which item is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to build a page where there are two main items on the top of the page, and according to whichever is clicked the content of the page changes to that products content.

For example, I have

```
<div class='item1'>
<img>
</div>

<div class='item2'>
<img>
</div>

<div class='contentItem1'>
</div>
<div class='contentItem1'>
</div>
<div class='contentItem1'>
</div>

<div class='contentItem2'>
</div>
<div class='contentItem2'>
</div>
<div class='contentItem2'>
</div>
```

I tried to give each item a key, so that I can target it with the data-id tag, however, that does not seem to work at all, or I am doing something wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit:

I should have added more info about how the structure looks like exactly:

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)
    <div data-id="{{$key}}" class="mainItem item{{key}}">
        <img>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Afterwards a several content blocks will be generated for each of the main item:

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)
  <div class="contentBlock{{key}}" id="contentBlock">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="contentBlock{{key}}" id="contentBlock">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="contentBlock{{key}}" id="contentBlock">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

I hope it makes sense. What I would like to do here, once the page is opened, only the content for item 1 is visible, however, once item2 is clicked, its content becomes visible but the item1's hides.

Comment: please provide logic, so that we could resolve the issue

Comment: Use a common class not unique ones. Then you can hide all easily and use other attributes or indexing to target the one you need

Comment: I think you want implement it with tabs.